# Get list of plugins from external Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, list, external, fetch

I was wondering How I can make a PHP script that fetch all active plugins from a external Wordpress website. So I can make easy a excel sheet from all the websites with active Wordpress plugins. I have already found a website (http://www.wpthemedetector.com) but I wan't to do it automatically.

Comment: `** NOTE: not intended for hacking. **` You killed me...

Comment: @Med it was not a joke at all.....

Comment: Yeah we know you are just kidding! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. And if you could some would argue that it is a information disclosure vulnerability of some sort.

The only sure way to get the current active plugins is by querying the database by using `$active_plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' );`. But that is only for the current web site and not exposed externally.

The reason services such as WP Theme Detector can detect the currently active theme is because the theme information is embedded in the theme's css file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have access to both sites as an admin. Then you can write a plugin to query the other site using the HTTP API or use the WP REST API plugin. This is not a weird question, there are many uses for this sort of thing in a network of sites.

https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Comment: At present, the rest api doesn't have the option to do this.